# How to configure multiples NodeJS sites in one NGINX server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2, rhel7

I need to configure multiples instances of NodeJS applications in one NGINX application server (version 1.10.2 - RHEL 7.2).
These instances are: Web site and API for development and testing environments.

Someone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to install nginx and run web server on nodejs?

Comment: @Aditya, yes I have one single application running on the nginx, but I need to configure more endpoints

Comment: Would you like to share what config are you using in nginx. I am interested in knowing if you are using paths in url like I suggested or are you using different ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already installed node.js, and you are running webserver on it then just choose two different ports, say one for production and one for testing purposes(may be staging).

After installing nginx configure it as follows:-

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;

  location /production {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location /testing {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

}
```

here change example.com with your domain name if any or localhost

suppose you run nodejs production webserver on 8080 you could choose a subpath for it say **localhost/production**. 
And similarly for testing, if you run web server at 8081 then choose a path like, **localhost/testing**.

I believe this will solve your problem.

If you dont wanna use urls like /production and /testing, you can use different ports.

If you have a domain "yourdomain.com"
So e.g. Production can run at yourdomain.com and staging(testing) can run at testing.yourdomain.com

for this nginx configuration will be

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  testing.yourdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yourdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Where 8080 is port where nodejs production webserver runs

and 8081 is testing webserver port used in nodejs

Comment: Worth noting that you could also do it with subdomains rather than paths.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly

Comment: and in node js server.js what is setting ? server.listen(8080) ?